# Blank field when I send a variable to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a form where the variable fields is sent to a database in phpmyadmin. The problem is that the fields in phpmyadmin are blank, as if I hadn't write anything in the form. The code is the following in PHP:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$institution = $_POST["institution"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$hcp = $_POST["hcp"];
$texto = $_POST["texto"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$license = $_POST["license"];

$connection = mysql_connect($database_host, $database_username, $database_password);
if(!$connection) { // if our attempt to connect failed
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database_name, $connection) or die("You cannot select data base");


$consulta = ("INSERT INTO `1264`(`name`, `institution`, `email` , `country`, `hcp` , `texto` , `state` , `license`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$institution."','".$email."','".$country."','".$hcp."','".$texto."','".$state."','".$license."');");
    echo $consulta; die;

mysql_query($consulta,$connection) or die("You cannot register. Try it later, please.");
```

And in HTML the format of the form is the following:

```
<form method="post" action="php/enviar.php">


    <span class="texto azul">Name</span><input class="caja texto" name="name" type="text"/><br /><br />
<span class="texto azul">Institution</span><input class="caja texto" name="institution" type="text"/><br /><br />
 <span class="texto azul">Email address</span><input class="caja texto" name="email" type="text"/><br /><br />

<span class="texto azul">Country</span><select id="country" class="caja texto" name="country">
<option value="">Country...</option>

 <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
...
</select>
<div id="fadein">
        <span id="usa" class="texto azul inputText">HCP Designation</span><select name="hcp" class="caja inputText texto" disabled>
            <option value="des">Designation...</option>
            <option value="md">MD</option>
            <option value="np">NP</option>
            <option value="rn">RN</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <span id="texto" class="texto azul inputText">If other, please specify</span>
        <textarea class="caja inputText texto" name="texto" disabled></textarea><br /><br />
        <span class="texto azul inputText">State of Licensure</span><input class="caja inputText texto" name="state" type="text" disabled/><br /><br />
        <span class="texto azul inputText">License number</span><input class="caja inputText texto" name="license" type="text" disabled/><br /><br />

</div>
        </form>
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't accept the fields that I write in the form?

Comment: Because you advised your script to die before running the query, have a look at `echo $consulta; die;` You're using a deprecated API, you're wide open to sql injection. So it's for the better.

Comment: I have deleted echo $consulta; die; but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Anything being printed out on the page?

Comment: The page works like if it had been sent perfect. It appears the last page, with the "thanks" message and the message saying that you have applied properly. But the problem is placed in phpmyadmin, where I see white fields in the database. I can only see the ID because is A/I.

Comment: So that means the insert query is running. Just after `$license = $_POST["license"];`, put `print_r($_POST);die();` and see what is printed out on the page

Comment: This is what is printed: Array ( )

Comment: So that's the issue there. Nothing is being posted by the form. I see that the HTML you posted only contains 1 element named `name`. Where are the others? Where is the form closing tag?

Comment: Yes, I have the others and the closed tag but it was a really long code because the country select is massive.

Comment: I have added the most of the code over here :)

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension has been deprecated since 2012, in favor of the mysqli and PDO extensions. It's use is highly discouraged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: So... how should I write the code instead mysql...???

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem.

```
echo $consulta; die;
```

You're instructing the script to exit even before getting to the `mysql_query($consulta,$connection)` line. Remove the `die` and it should be good to go provided your connection is good and there's no syntax error in your query.

You also don't require the `(` and `)` when storing the query as string. So

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO `1264`(`name`, `institution`, `email` , `country`, `hcp` , `texto` , `state` , `license`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$institution."','".$email."','".$country."','".$hcp."','".$texto."','".$state."','".$license."')";
```

***Sidenote***: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated post v5.5. Switch to PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should first check post array you get.

Do this first:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);exit;
```

Check what values you get.

**Note**: Also check value name fields in form & key of post array should be same.

Also replace query with given below.

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO `1264`(`name`, `institution`, `email` , `country`, `hcp` , `texto` , `state` , `license`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$institution."','".$email."','".$country."','".$hcp."','".$texto."','".$state."','".$license."')";
```

Comment: This is debugging. More apt to post it as a comment.

Comment: As @aspirin said this isn't answering the question.

Comment: @TerryHarvey as he said then why you are saying again :P try not to be too chatty

Comment: @RakeshShetty I had originally posted something else, but decided to remove it. Instead of removing the comment, I just edited it.

Comment: @AnandSolanki My comment was automatically added by the reviewing process of posts automatically tagged as "Low Quality Post".

Comment: Can't help but comment this - AnandSolanki got trolled by the system :p